# Como nomear um arquivo texto com informações de um EditText?

Tags: java, android-studio

No meu aplicativo de cadastro tenho as informações de nome e telefone. Após inserir as informações e clicar em cadastrar, um arquivo texto é criado com as informações cadastradas.

Porém gostaria que o arquivo texto criado fosse nomeado com a informação do campo nome.

Exemplo:

> Nome: Joao
> Telefone: 123

Arquivo texto criado: **Joao.txt**

Atualmente, crio e nomeio o arquivo com o seguinte comando:

```
FileOutputStream ArqTexto = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Clientes.txt");
```

Já armazenei o valor inserido no campo nome em uma variável, mas não sei como fazer a sintaxe correta.

Tentei assim:

```
FileOutputStream ArqTexto = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + VariavelNome +".txt");
```

Porém não funcionou.

Comment: Faltou uma `/` entre o diretório e sua `VariavelNome`.

Comment: Grande @PauloRodrigues muito obrigado! Era isso mesmo!

Comment: É interessante também você remover possíveis caracteres especiais quando der nomes para estes arquivos, pois em alguns casos o seu aplicativo pode dar um *force close*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O correto é:

```
FileOutputStream ArqTexto = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/"+ VariavelNome +".txt");
```

Faltou a barra.